# How to display InMobi Ads banner in browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, inmobi

I want to showcase my inmobi Ads banner in browser like chrome or safari, but what I get is only a white banner. Nothing about Ads is display in the banner. I am doing like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var inmobi_conf = {
    siteid : 'f2aca88ff3d94715b354dd6af9da8326',
    slot : "15",
    sticky: "bottom"
};
</script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cf.cdn.inmobi.com/ad/inmobi.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did you get any solution?